# Laravel validation regex, breaks in view

Tags: php, html, regex, validation, laravel

So, I have the following rules in my model:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'name'            => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:subsidiaries',
    'internal_number' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:subsidiaries',
    'expedition_rate' => array('required', 'regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.?)[0-9]{1,2}$/'),
    'hundred_kg_rate' => array('regex:/^[0-9]{1,5}(\.?)[0-9]{1,2}$/'),
    'handling'        => array('regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.?)[0-9]{1,2}$/'),
    'insurance'       => 'required|numeric',
);
```

But, for some reason, when the regex is applied in the `pattern` attribute tag in html... it breaks!

Result:

```
<input required="true" pattern="^[0-9]{" class="form-control" ....>
                               _________
                                 \
                                  => This right here should be
                               ^[0-9]{1,3}(\.?)[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Comment: Where are you outputting it, though? Are you using `Former`, by any chance?

Comment: @Raphael_ Actually, I am using `Former`... the rules are passed on from the controller to the view

Comment: Then this is really an issue with Former, not Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Try using like this.

```
array(
    'field' => 'regex:[a-z]'
);
```

Hope this would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the curly braces... I bet PHP is expecting to parse a variable inside, like this:

```
$var = 'something';
echo 'The value is {$var}.';
// Outputs:
// The value is something.
```

Contrast this with:

```
$var = 'something';
echo 'The value is \{$var\}.';
// Outputs:
// The value is $var.
```

The part that confuses me though, is that these are within single quotes, and so this shouldn't happen. Maybe a Laravel thing?

Comment: How can one, escape curly braces in a regex syntax? This is new for me

Comment: Double all of the backslashes.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. To escape the curly brace, you should just be able to do `\{...\}`. When it renders, it shouldn't have that backslash.

Comment: I have tried it, with no positive effect. But the problem I don't think it's the backslash, since if I do `{1\\,3}` I'll eventually get a `"^[0-9]{1"` and no more

Comment: That's weird. You may want to ask this question over at Laravel's GitHub... It might very well be a bug. I looked at their validation test cases, and none of them include curly braces: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/571c04ac7827c2652402f9c40271415eaab6e81c/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php

Comment: Well, somebody replied my question in Laravel's forums... and it seems that it might be a bug: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=56239#p56239

Comment: Interesting. In your case, rather than write a custom validator, you could instead just rewrite your RegEx to not include that comma. For example, `x{1,3}` can also be represented as `xx?x?`. At any rate, good luck with your project!